# React Share variables between components

Tags: reactjs, properties, components

I have three Components.
App is the Parent component.
Tools and DrawingBoard are child Components.
I want to transfer Data between the Tools and DrawingBoard Component.

```
export default class App extends  Component{
  getFormData(name, value){
   //empty so far
}
 render(){
   return(
    <div className="main-container">
        <DrawingBoard  styledata={???} />
        <Tools  data={this.getFormData.bind(this)}/>
   </div>
  );
}
```

I pass the function getFormData as a property to Tools to get its data.
Now I want to pass name and value, preferably as an associative array or object
with arr["name"] = value as a property to DrawingBoard.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `state` in `App` component which you can change it inside `Tools` and new `state` pass to `DrawingBoard`,

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      styledata: {}
    };
  }

  getFormData(name, value) {
    this.setState({
      styledata: { [name]: value }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="main-container">
      <DrawingBoard styledata={ this.state.styledata } />
      <Tools data={ this.getFormData.bind(this) } />
    </div>
  }
}

class Tools extends React.Component {
  getData() {
    // Load data
    // 
    this.props.data('color', 'red');
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={ this.getData.bind(this) }>Change Data</button>
    </div>
  }
}

class DrawingBoard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1 style={ this.props.styledata }>DrawingBoard</h1>
    </div>
  }
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/42036/)

Comment: using this.getData.bind(this) directly reduce the performance of the app, as it re-render the component, therefore use 'this.getData = this,getData.bind(this)' in the constructor. For more information visit ' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVWpBtRjkCk&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwgg3vaYJgHGnModB54rxOk3&index=14 '